# AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

This control has a property Enabled that acts exactly as Visible behaves i.e. ?.Enabled = false hides the control.

I need to be able to keep all the tabs visible but some to be disabled under code control.

Any hints as to how I can achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: so you would like the tab to be visible, but stop the user from changing to that tab if they click on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Enabled` property for `TabPanel`.

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer 
      ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1"   runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1"></ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2"></ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" Enabled="False" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3"></ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Or in code-behind,

```
TabContainer1.Tabs[0].Enabled = false;
```

Comment: :This seems to have the same effect as setting the enabled property for the tabs.

Comment: @AAsk My bad! I forgot the magic ball. Please edit your post and add that code.

Comment: if (!AISHtmlBuilder.showTab("4", showtabs)) { tabpnlPhotos.Enabled = false; } 

if (!AISHtmlBuilder.showTab("5", showtabs)) { tabsModManager.Tabs[5].Enabled = false; }

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution using client-side scripting.  Basically, handle the `OnClientActiveTabChanged` event for the `TabContainer` (which fires whenever the active tab is changed).  Then, if the tab is one that you don't want the user to use, change the `ActiveTabIndex` property of the `TabContainer` back to one that is acceptable.

**Tab Container:**

```
<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" 
    Height="126px" Width="400px" ClientIDMode="Predictable" 
    onclientactivetabchanged="tabClickCheck" >
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel1">
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="TabPanel3">
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

**Javascript handler:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function tabClickCheck() {
        var tabCont = document.getElementById("<%=TabContainer1.ClientID %>").control;
        var tabInd = tabCont.get_activeTabIndex();
        tabCont.set_activeTabIndex(2);
    }
</script>
```

This function just sets the `ActiveTabIndex` to `2`, regardless of which tab you clicked (you'll notice I'm also getting the current `ActiveTabIndex`, but I don't do anything with it - that's just to show you how).  Obviously, use whatever logic makes sense for your app =)